# Wordpress multi-vendor setup for deals website, allow sellers to maintain deals

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I know that Woocommerce has a multi-vendor feature that allows other vendors to sell on your website but I'm looking for specific functionality related to that.

Does anyone know of a plugin/theme that allows vendors to track/fulfill order and most importantly, input tracking for their own orders? I want to create a single page with deals instead of multiple stores.

Comment: Please note *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam"*: [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

Yes brother there is a theme " Dokan " which allows the vendor / seller and also admin to track and keep full record !

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Dokan Theme from weDevs http://wedevs.com/theme/dokan/ 
Its a full featured multivendor ecommerce WordPress app theme based on WooCommerce. Hopefully it will help you.